# Remove jQuery scripts depending on user agent

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad, jquery-mobile

I am creating a parallax site using the Stellar.js script, however i want to disable this script when being viewed on a tablet or phone.
Is there a way of telling certain devices to call a script and others not? I am able to call different css files depending on the browsing device, but this method won't call then run jQuery scripts?!

```
{document.write("<link type=\"text\/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css\/style.css\" \/>");
document.write("<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"js\/jquery.stellar.min.js\" ><\/script>"
);}
```

The full html can be found here
http://bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/Boutinot/index.txt.

This is my first site i'm attempting to make cross platform, so i apologise if these seem like basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap an if statement around the script plugin depending on the screen resolution? Or you can use media queries [like this example](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html)